# Display an image in Java Swt?

Tags: java, swt

i'm new to Java and Swt. I would like to simply display an image Splash Screen of my application. I can't find any "image widget".

How can i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is an "image widget" in SWT. Rather, you can render the image in SWT widgets.

For example, the [Label](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Label.html) widget:

```
...set up...
Shell shell = new Shell(SWT.ON_TOP);
Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
label.setImage(someImage);
...more set up...
shell.open();
```

In regards to your overall goal: [SWT splash screen example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CreateasplashscreeninSWT.htm)